# Why is Eclipse is not pushing the latest version of the app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using java on eclipse and learning how to make apps for android. I wrote a very simple "Hello World" app that just displays the text to make sure the app runs.

Then I started making additions to the code but the device still displayed helloworld only so I simply wrote the following and tried to run it, since there were no errors here.

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    System.out.println("Hello, World1");
    System.out.println("Hello, World2");

    }
}
```

On the console, I got

```
[2014-01-07 23:35:09 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2014-01-07 23:35:09 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-01-07 23:35:09 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-07 23:35:09 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity    activity launch
[2014-01-07 23:35:13 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device xxxx-number removed by me-xxxx
[2014-01-07 23:35:13 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2014-01-07 23:35:15 - HelloWorld] Success!
[2014-01-07 23:35:16 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.example.helloworld.MainActivity on device xxxx-number removed by me-xxxx
[2014-01-07 23:35:16 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]cmp=com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity }
```

I have cleaned the project and uninstalled the app from the device manually and retried running it but I am still getting the old "Hello, World" instead of "Hello, World1" and "Hello, World2".

What am I doing wrong here? Apologies if it is something obvious, I am not great at java or android.

Comment: uhh because you dont call that method...?

Comment: Wait, doesn't void main run automatically like in C++?

Comment: On desktop, sure. But you're on Android now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work. This is not "Java" as you know it. You don't need a main method. What you are probably seeing is the `activity_main.xml` inside the `layout` folder. There you will find your `Hello, World` message, which is probably referencing a string declared at `strings.xml`, located at the folder `values`. Both folders are located inside the `res` folder (RESources).

You may probably want to read a little bit the Android Docummentation at [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. It has been a frustrating few hours.

Comment: @user3170281 Your welcome. If it helped you solve your problem, then you should accept the answer to help others with the same problem find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you shouldn't use main(String[] args) inside an Activity (it shouldn't be launched). This is not a Java Program

Secondly:

Sometimes its needed to regenerate bin folder at project.

Try this:

1. Select and delete all resources and folder at bin folder.
2. Clean app.
3. Relaunch app.

Maybe this can help....
Good luck!